# Trouble using np.append with 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

So i'm trying to append 2 np array together but it gives me this error `ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)`I know that this mean the shape of the array are not the same but I don't understand why and how to fix it.

```
arr1 = np.array([
 [10.24217065  5.63381577]
 [ 2.71521988 -3.33068004]
 [-3.43022486 16.40921457]
 [ 1.4461307  12.59851726]
 [12.34829023 29.67531647] 
 [16.65382971  9.8915765 ]])

arr2 = np.array([4.62643996 5.14587112])

arr3 = np.append(arr1,arr2,axis=0)
```

Comment: `np.vstack((arr1,arr2))`

Comment: It should be obvious to you that `arr1` is 2d with shape (6,2), and `arr2` is 1d with shape (2,).  If not, then you need to read some more `numpy` basics.

Comment: `np.append` with `axis` parameter just uses `np.concatenate([ arg1, args2], axis=0)`.  Concatenate is picky about the number of dimensions, and patching shapes.  I'd recommend staying away from `np.append`, and learn enough about dimensions to use `np.concatenate` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Simply make them the same dimension:

```py
arr3 = np.append(arr1, [arr2], axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

`arr2` has only a single dimension, since its shape is `(2,)`. `arr1` on the other hand has two dimensions, since its shape is `(6, 2)`. These aren't compatible for `np.append`, as it says.

You can make `arr2` have the required number of dimensions in many ways. One of them is reshaping:

```py
arr3 = np.append(arr1, arr2.reshape(1, 2), axis=0)
```

At this point, the arrays have shape `(6, 2)` and `(1, 2)`, which `np.append` knows how to deal with. The output will have shape `(7, 2)`.

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you exactly what is the problem. The first array has two dimensions and the second array has one dimension. Another pair of [ ] in the second array will do the job.

```
arr2 = np.array([[4.62643996 5.14587112]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr3 = np.vstack((arr1, arr2))
```

or if you really want to use `append`, my favorite is

```
arr3 = np.append(arr1, arr2[np.newaxis, :])
```